# Onclick show submenu but hide other submenu(s)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, menu, submenu

I am using jQuery UI menu widget to have  header navigation on my pages

here is a mock up http://jsfiddle.net/ctL6T/1/

My issue is i want to close any other shown submenus if another main menu is clicked, you can see in my fiddle if you click one main stub, the submenu stays open if you click another main stub

i thought by using an $.each on the click event, i could by using the same code that toggles iterate through the elements and flip them back and forth, but this opens the opposite menu

```
        $('.has-sub').on('click', function(){
            $('#mainmenu li').each(function () {
                $(".submenu" ).toggle();
            });
            $(this).toggleClass('ui-state-active').children('span').toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-icon-triangle-1-n');
            return false;
         });
```

and this is just a mess

```
 $('.has-sub').on('click', function(){
$('#mainmenu li').each(function () {
  $(".submenu" ).toggle();
  $(this).toggleClass('ui-state-active').children('span').toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-icon-triangle-1-n');
});
return false;
 });
```

as always any help is appreciated

*due to flashing of unstyled content, i decided to have the main menu as static html using some jquery ui theme classes, it should not effect the functionality of what im asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {

            $( ".submenu" ).menu({
                position: {at: "left bottom"},
                icons: { submenu: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s" }
            });
            $('.has-sub').on('click', function(){
                $(this).next(".submenu").toggle();
                $(this).toggleClass('ui-state-active').children('span').toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-icon-triangle-1-n');
                $('.has-sub').not($(this)).each(function(){
                   $(this).next(".submenu").hide();
                    $(this).removeClass('ui-state-active');
                });
                return false;
                });     
});
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/ctL6T/6/

Comment: it does show hide submenus like i asked, but addes some new issues , it doesnt rehide the submenu on a subsequent reclick of the same element, and main stub menus still stay highlighted

Comment: Try the new one, I fixed it. http://jsfiddle.net/ctL6T/6/ (gotta  toggle the triangle icon, but that's easy)

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to trigger an event when you click any of the `<a>` elements within the navigation. When you click on one of the `<a>` elements within `#mainmenu` all elements with a class of `submenu` will be hidden. Also, any elements with a class of `ui-state-active` will have the `ui-state-active` class removed.

Here's what I added to make it all work!

```
$('#mainmenu a').on('click', function(){
    $('.submenu').hide();
    $('.ui-state-active').removeClass('ui-state-active');
});
```

And here's a fiddle! http://jsfiddle.net/ctL6T/5/

**REVISED VERSION**

I added in some additional logic to ensure that when you click a link it will close out the drop-down menus. If you click on a link within a drop-down it will close the drop-down navigation and remove the active state. Also, if you click on the home link it will close the drop-down navigation and remove the active state.

This should help ya out!

Fiddles: http://jsfiddle.net/ctL6T/8/

Comment: ok, so the additional issue this creates is, if i reclick a menu item while a submenu is open , how can it hide the submenu?

Comment: Hey Jay - I revised my post and added some additional logic. Should be helpful.